# WSO2 API Manager & Web Service composition

Tags: web-services, api, wso2, composition, wso2-api-manager

Here's the scenario,

- *WS_A* and *WS_B* are Web Services published in different endpoints.
- *WS_A* receives *personId*, makes some processing, logs some data, and returns the *name* and the *lastname* of the *Person* with *personId*.
- *WS_B* receives two Strings *name* and *lastname* and saves *name+lastname* in a database, then returns Ok/Error.

I need to publish an API *API_Composition*, using WSO2 API Manager, that will call *WS_A*, and send the result to *WS_B*, then return the result of *WS_B*.

Keep in mind that i can't make a new *WS_C* that has the behaviour of *WS_A+WS_B*, because i can't access the whole code of any of them.

Is there a way of doing this using only WSO2 API Manager?
Are there any other API Management products that can accomplish this requirement?

Regards

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't access the whole code of any of them"? If you have access to the endpoints and you know the input and output of each of the services you should be able to create a composed service C.

Comment: No Sir, the input and the output might be known, but not the whole code.

Comment: That's the purpose of a Web Service or any Interface. For example, what if i access the Person with Id=1 and the code notificates someone, or generates some kind of special log..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with mediator sequence. I have not found a specific tutorial for your scenario, but [here's a blog post that has a demo on using mediator sequences and links to detailed documentation](http://wso2.com/blogs/cloud/the-power-of-mediators-api-call-transformation-and-orchestration/).

(Note: the demo and blog post are for [WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud) - the hosted version of WSO2 API Manager. But it all works the same for API Manager - it is the same technology.)